# Looking For a Simile For Something That Follows You Around

Tags: simile

I'm writing a blog post about the impacts of an autoimmune disease. The sentence I'm trying to construct looks like this:

"The disease importunately follows me around like a god damn..."

I'm struggling to come up with something better than "... Puppy who lost his ball."

Any suggestions? The cruder, the better. A pop culture reference would be awesome!

I'm stuck.

Comment: I just thought out Richard Sherman on Michael Crabtree... But there has to be better out there. What does Kanye West follow around?

Comment: "...follows me around like it's my shadow."

Comment: Make something up.  ... Like toilet paper stuck to your shoe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I would love to brainstorm with you about the crudest possible metaphors *in private*, I'll confine my comment here to how I would construct these:

- Think of bad people.
- Think of edgy, cool, or comical agents such as sharks or tax collectors.
- Think of culturally relevant people (though your writing will age better if the subject is culturally relevant on a long term basis).
- What are these people obsessed with, or negatively associated with in the media? Or what do they mainly do?
- Who do these people love, harm, or hate? Where do these people find
  targets?
- Can the target be adapted to a more comical form, such as changing "surfers" to "hipsters", "fish" to "baby seals"?
- Additionally, consider anything that "stalks" such as predatory cats.

You will generate associations. Filter the associations for those that involve following. Pick one that fits your tone.

Comment: This was all great! Thank you for taking the time to write this all out.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with "Follows me around like a teenager handing me a mask."

For your purposes *Reprovingly* would work but is almost antique.

reprovingly - in a reproving or reproachful manner; "she spoke to him reprovingly"

*Reproachfully* is only slightly better.  I'm kind of getting away from how it follows and more towards how it makes you feel; *Miserably*, Pathetically...

How about ***Accusingly***. There! That's it for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about stalker? From M-W:

> **[stalker](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stalker)**: a person who stalks : a person who pursues someone obsessively and aggressively to the point of harassment

You example:

> "The disease importunately follows me around like a god damn **stalker**."

Just to be clear, **stalker** is a metaphor for the autoimmune disease. You just can't make it go away. You can replace "goddamn" with a cruder adjective, if you'd like.